# How can I make my select statement deterministically match only 1/n of my dataset?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-science

I'm processing data from a MySQL table where each row has a UUID associated with it.  EDIT: the "UUID" is in fact an MD5 hash (VARCHAR) of the job text.

My select query looks something like:

`SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1`

I am only running one worker node right now, but would like to scale it out to several nodes without altering my schema.

The issue is that the jobs take some time, and scaling out beyond one right now would introduce a race condition where several nodes are working on the same job before it completes and the row  is updated.

Is there an elegant way to effectively "shard" the data on the client-side, by specifying some modifier config value per worker node?  My first thought was to use the MOD function like this:

`SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE UUID MOD 2 = 0 ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1`
and `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE UUID MOD 2 = 1 ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1`

In this case I would have two workers configured as "0" and "1".  But this isn't giving me an even distribution (not sure why) and feels clunky.  Is there a better way?

Comment: What type is your UUID column, and which version of UUID are you using?

Comment: Its' VARCHAR.  And I may need to correct...I am technically not using UUID, the ID in this case is an MD5 hash of the job.

Comment: Edit that into your question, please. MD5 should do better than a UUIDv1 which is not random, but if it's a varchar you're trying to use a string like `acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8` as a number which should always get you 0.

Comment: Does `select uuid mod 2 from jobs` give you anything but 0?

Comment: Yes, interestingly it gives 0 for 72% of rows and 1 for the rest.

Comment: Ok, I see what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're storing the ID as a hex string like `acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8`. MySQL will not convert the hex for you. Instead, if it starts with a letter you get 0. If it starts with a number, you get the starting numbers.

- select '123abc' + 0 = 123
- select 'abc123' + 0 = 0

6 out of 16 will start with a letter so they will all be 0 and 0 mod anything is 0. The remaining 10 of 16 will be some number so will be distributed properly, 5 of 16 will be 0, 5 of 16 will be 1. 6/16 + 5/16 = 69% will be 0 which is very close to your observed 72%.

---

To do this right we need to convert the 128 hex string into a 64 bit unsigned integer.

1. Slice off 64 bits with either `left(uuid, 16)` or `right(uuid, 16)`.
2. Convert the hex (base 16) into decimal (base 10) using [`conv`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv).
3. [`cast`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cast/) the result to an unsigned bigint. If we skip this step MySQL appears to use a float which loses accurracy.

```
select cast(conv(right(uuid, 16), 16, 10) as unsigned) mod 2
```

Beautiful.

That will only use 64 bits of the 128 bit checksum, but for this purpose that should be fine.

---

Note this technique works with an MD5 checksum because it is pseudorandom. It will *not* work with the default MySQL [uuid()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function which is a [UUID version 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)). UUIDv1 is a timestamp + a fixed ID and will always mod the same.

[UUIDv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)), which is a random number, will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  I am tying it but very strangely getting the exact same value for conv(uuid, 16, 10) across all my rows

Comment: @OriginalRockers Could you show some samples of `select uuid, conv(uuid, 16, 10) from jobs`?

Comment: '0080cb9b5af0a27963c8e896eeff396e', '18446744073709551615'

'00b1e1e82a14f6f4d7d0aa21014adff4', '18446744073709551615'

'00b2f11d37337f3494a62916f668432f', '18446744073709551615'

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling with formatting but '18446744073709551615' is the only value for conv(uuid, 16, 10).  I must be hitting some limit because conv(substring(uuid, 1, 10), 16, 10) works beautifully

Comment: @OriginalRockers Ok, got it all figured out. Slice off 64 bits. Convert from hex to decimal. Cast to unsigned bigint to avoid an implicit cast to float.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the hex string to decimal before modding:

```
where CONV(substring(uuid, 1, 8), 16, 10) mod 2 = 1
```

A reasonable hashing function should distribute evenly enough for this purpose.

Use substring to convert only a small part so the conv doesn't overflow decimal range and maybe behave badly. Any subset of bits should also be well distributed.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but very strangely I am getting exactly the same value for CONV(uuid, 16, 10) across all my rows.  I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: ...but this strategy does work nicely when I reduce the length of uuid like so:
where CONV(substring(uuid, 1, 10), 16, 10) mod 2 = 1

Comment: This only uses 32 bits. You can use 64 bits, but you must cast to an unsigned integer.

Comment: @Schwern 32 bits, so ±2 billion, is plenty.